# Set Random Text To Multiple TextView Without Any Repetition

Tags: android, random, textview

Hello Guys I am New to Android. I am developing an App but stuck here. I want to set Random Text to TextView and I did it successfully but I am getting same text on all textview I put it. I want if the text set to one textview should not be show to other means its should not be repeat. Any help must be appreciated. I am posting some code here.

```
int[] array_set_up_text;
Random rand_set_up_text;

rand_set_up_text = new Random();
    array_set_up_text = new int[] { R.string.set_up_text1,  R.string.set_up_text2, R.string.set_up_text3,
            R.string.set_up_text4, R.string.set_up_text5, R.string.set_up_text6, R.string.set_up_text7,
             R.string.set_up_text8,R.string.set_up_text9,R.string.set_up_text10,R.string.set_up_text11,R.string.set_up_text12};
    rand_text_set_up = rand_set_up_text.nextInt(array_set_up_text.length - 1);

text1.setText(array_set_up_text[rand_text_set_up]);
text2.setText(array_set_up_text[rand_text_set_up]);
text3.setText(array_set_up_text[rand_text_set_up]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line

```
 rand_text_set_up = rand_set_up_text.nextInt(array_set_up_text.length - 1);
```

You get a random position once, then don't update it.

Easiest solution is to do something like below

```
rand_text_set_up = rand_set_up_text.nextInt(array_set_up_text.length - 1);
text2.setText(array_set_up_text[rand_text_set_up]);

//Get a new random position.
rand_text_set_up = rand_set_up_text.nextInt(array_set_up_text.length - 1);
text3.setText(array_set_up_text[rand_text_set_up]);

//Get a new random position.
rand_text_set_up = rand_set_up_text.nextInt(array_set_up_text.length - 1);
text3.setText(array_set_up_text[rand_text_set_up]);
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code to:

```
text1.setText(array_set_up_text[rand_set_up_text.nextInt(array_set_up_text.length)]);
text2.setText(array_set_up_text[rand_set_up_text.nextInt(array_set_up_text.length)]);
text3.setText(array_set_up_text[rand_set_up_text.nextInt(array_set_up_text.length)]);
```

Comment: I corrected the code. I had an error at first, too.

Comment: If this worked for you, please accept my answer. Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to recall the nextInt() method each time:

```
text1.setText(array_set_up_text[rand_text_set_up]);
rand_set_up_text.nextInt()
text2.setText(array_set_up_text[rand_text_set_up]);
rand_set_up_text.nextInt()
text3.setText(array_set_up_text[rand_text_set_up]);
```